# Sorting out a href in html5

Tags: html

I am trying to add the twitter share button with some text and hashtag on my website. But however I find that the final result misses the text and hashtag. Can anyone correct me? This was the code I was trying.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url="http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/PServer/results.jsp?output=+ID" text= My Results &hashtags=UMCProteinServer" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your href should change to something like this, its not a valid url:

```
<c:url value="http://twitter.com/share" var="twitterUrl">
  <c:param name="url" value="http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/PServer/results.jsp?output=" + ID />
  <c:param name="text" value="My Results" />
  <c:param name="hashtags" value="UMCProteinServer" />
</c:url>

href="${twitterUrl}"
```

Comment: Can you give a complete statement buddy?. I think I am getting closer.

Comment: I think if you are still having issues with this it is because of the output=+ID. Is ID a javascript variable?

Comment: Yeah. It's a dynamic integer value. Can you change the statement accordingly. Appreciate it.

Comment: oh Sorry, you're not even using JS, whatever language you are using you need to URL Encode each of the 3 query string values so that the url is safe. What language are you using?

Comment: I updated my answer. I've never used jsp, so I'm not sure how much sense this makes. But I googled how to encode a url in jsp and this is what I found. It looks like it should work except for maybe the + ID part I added. If you know how to concat a string in jsp that is all it is doing

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url="http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/PServer/results.jsp?output=+ID" text=" My Results'&hashtags=UMCProteinServer'" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all the properties, the url, the text, and the hashtags to be all part of the url, so to do that, you would need to remove the second " since that cuts the url off after `url=`. In addition you need to url encode the url. So the link and button should look something like this:

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fprotein.rnet.missouri.edu%3A8080%2FPServer%2Fresults.jsp%3Foutput%3D%2BID&text=My Results&hashtags=UMCProteinServer" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks good but the id in the above link is a dynamic interger value. Can you make changes accordingly and repost it?.

Comment: you'd have to set it via some javascript or set it through the templating engine you're using